# Is it possible to embed Fuse IDE in a javaFX application?

Tags: javafx-2, apache-camel, fuseesb

I’m contributing in an Enterprise Integration Infrastructure project. Like many other integration software, `Apache-Camel` is the core of our application. To enable users defining their `EIPs` graphically, I want to use Fuse IDE in the software. The only thing I need the Fuse do is generating xml file from the routes which are defined by the users.

On the other hand, I know that Fuse IDE is essentially an Eclipse plugin (I think it is an Eclipse RCP plugin). Since the UI of our application is based on `javaFX` I want to know that is there any way to manipulate the code of Fuse to adjust it to javaFX entities?

Your help will be more than appreciated, due to the high importance of this issue for me.

Comment: I hope these users are trained people that will be using this tool as you can create absolute havoc giving someone with no training in EIP this type of power.

Comment: @namphibian Thanks for the caution, you are scrutator! I think EIP (Enterprise Integration Pattern) is a recursive concept. You can define a route with basic EIPs like `choice`, `when`, etc. then  you can use this route as a composed EIP in other routes. So, I think we can use the term EIP for both the basic EIPs and routes. In our case, We will create composed EIPs ourselves and users will use these EIPs along with the basic ones to define their routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a lot of hard work as that code is tightly coupled to Eclipse.

So I would say NO unless you are prepared to do a lot of work porting and migration the code.

Comment: Claus, thank you for the answer. I read your notes before and I know who you are. AFAIK, Fuse and Talend are the only specific-purpose tools for defining routes for Camel, but none of them is adequate for my application. Other graph based tools like Activiti and Jung only offer graph interface and tuning them to be enabled for creating routes is not such a good idea. I know you offer graphical presentation of the routes in Hawtio, but defining/creating routes graphically is another thing. All-told, what is your suggestion for me to do?

Comment: hawtio has also a UI editor for Camel. Its available from the wiki plugin, where you can create a new document and choose Camel.

Comment: You are quite right, I see it right now. I'm new to Camel and hawtio and so far I didn't checked wiki tab in hawtio. Usually wiki and help menus in the softwares are used for other purpose. Anyway, is it possible to use this plugin in javaFX or I need a wrapper?

Comment: the Camel editor is javascript code supporting HTML5. So if you can get en embedded web browser in javaFX then yeah that ought to do it - thought we did not write that Camel editor in mind for it to be used outside hawtio, so you may need to fork the code and tweak for it to work for you. Or if the changes is minimal then you are welcome to do PR for the hawtio project.

Comment: And there is also this Camel editor javascript library: http://giacomolm.github.io/Jel/

Comment: There is a Control in javaFX called WebView. I think I can load the Camel editor javascript library in it without any tweak! I’m going to do this … . If I encountered with a problem, can I disturb you again, please?

Comment: I suggest to ask on the hawtio community if you have such questions - http://hawt.io/community/index.html